# How can fb share have prefilled text in textarea "Say something about this"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-share

Here is my code :

```
<html class="">
<head>
<!--<![endif]-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta property="og:title" content="#shareacokesg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Personalise the iconic Coca-Cola can with a name and share a Coke with someone special today!" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://netbizlabs.com/coke/uploads/<?php echo $text;?>" />
```

Other content is working fine but I want to prefill the textarea which marked in red below :

[image]

Is this is possible? If yes then how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are **not allowed** to pre-fill the message part of any post or share – users have to enter it themselves.

See [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control), 3.3:

> *“Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing.”*

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with Facebook and OpenGraph.

The Facebook Open Graph Debugger gives all the information you can show in the share modal: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: so is there any alternative ways ?

Comment: @RakeshShetty Unfortunately not. You can't edit the text in that field. You have more options if you use Open Graph Stories from Facebook, but that does require more work (and you still can't edit the field, but it may be more appealing for the user). https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started